# Generic Float type in Julia language?

Tags: types, julia

My question is simple, is there a generic `Float` type in julia? For the case of `Integer`s, for example, one can simply write `Int` and it will be translated as `Int32` in 32-bit systems or `Int64` in 64-bit systems. For `Float`s though, see the example function below:

```
function bb(n)
    b = Array{Float64}(n) 
    b[1] = 0.9999
    for i = 2:n
        @inbounds b[i] = b[i-1] * 0.9999
    end    
    println(b[n])
end

bb(10^3)
@time bb(10^3)
@time bb(10^8)
```

It gives the following timing results along with total memory allocations:

```
0.9048328935585562
0.9048328935585562
  0.000100 seconds (135 allocations: 15.750 KB)
2.4703e-320
  3.230642 seconds (14 allocations: 762.940 MB, 1.51% gc time)
```

Now change the first line to `b = Array{AbstractFloat}(n)` and see the ridiculously huge timings and memory allocations:

```
0.9048328935585562
0.9048328935585562
  0.003564 seconds (2.13 k allocations: 46.953 KB)
2.4703e-320
  351.068176 seconds (200.00 M allocations: 3.725 GB, 0.74% gc time)
```

There is nothing as `b = Array{Float}(n)` I can use, the only solution I came up with is this non-elegant notation `b = Array{typeof(1.0)}(n)`.

Comment: Short answer: use Float64. If you insist do `const Float = typeof(1.0)` and use Float afterwards but the standard is Float64 (BTW `const`... is the new way to write `typealias`). Also, floating point numbers are a compromise. If you have special needs, you may need to think carefully which number type to use and there are quite a few in Julia.

Comment: @DanGetz -- Thank you for the reply. That raises another question, however, why didn't the Julia team add that elegant `const Float = typeof(1.0)`  to the Julia core? It would be easier for people to just write `Float` regardless of the underlying system.

Answer (score 11):

Your issue with Abstract Float is not to do with 32 Bit or 64 Bit.

Julia has no `Float` that matches `Int` because 
floating-point literals are **always** Float64.
I.e. On 64bit or 32bit systems `typeof(1.0)==Float64`.
(for a `Float32` literal use `1.0f0`)

If you really wanted one you would need to define it as

```
@static if Sys.WORDSIZE == 64
    const Float = Float64
else
    const Float = Float32
end
```

But this doesn't seem useful, since it wouldn't correspond to anything.
It wouldn't be a closer map to hardware even because the implementation of Floating point math in the CPU, is (generally) 64bit, even on 32Bit CPUs.

See: [this thread on Discourse`Float` type like `Int` type](http://discourse.julialang.org/t/float-type-like-int-type/1164).

There is no advantage to using Float32 on a 32 bit system, and Float64 on a 64 bit system.
There are advantages to using Float32 everywhere -- if you don't need the accuracy -- the key one being halving memory allocation -- which halves the time spent allocating, and the time spent on inter-process communication.

#### On to your performance issues:

The poor performance of `b = Array{AbstractFloat}(n)`
is because you are creating an container holding an abstract type.
See [performance tips: Avoid Containers with Abstract type parameters](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/performance-tips/#Avoid-containers-with-abstract-type-parameters-1)
These are slow, because they are basically arrays of pointers -- the pointer needs to be dereferenced each time an element is interacted with.
This is because such an array `b` has been declared to possibly contain elements of any number of different types. Some could be `Float16` others could be `Float32`, some might even be `BigFloat`s or an `ArbFloat{221}`.
So containers containing abstract types are slow to work with, because they are arrays of pointers.

So writing `b = Array{typeof(1.0)}(n)` is exactly equivalent to writing `b = Array{Float64}(n)`
Nothing is being done there.
So that is clearly not a solution to what your true problem is.

Assuming your true problem is that you want to specify the type returned then you should pass it in as a parameter:

```
function bb(T, n)
    b = Array{T}(n) 
    b[1] = 0.9999
    for i = 2:n
        @inbounds b[i] = b[i-1] * 0.9999
    end    
    println(b[n])
end
```

Call that with (for example) `bb(Float32, 100)`.
All the math is happening in Float64 since it is specified using Float64 literals, but when you assigned it to the array, `convert(T,...)` will implictly be called.

Alternatively you might want to pass in the values, and infer the type:

```
function bb(n, b1::T)
    b = Array{T}(n) 
    b[1] = b1
    for i = 2:n
        @inbounds b[i] = b[i-1] * b1
    end    
    println(b[n])
end
```

Call that with: `bb(100, 0.9999f0)`

Comment: +1 for the discourse link. This _does_ come up often. I feel the solution might be more along matlab lines, i.e. `const Single = Float32; const Double = Float64` rather than `const Float = Float64` (I do agree that just saying 'float' would be confusing to people thinking in c++)

Comment: I wouldn't define anything more in Base. I would just let it error, and let people google it and find the appropriate documentation (eg this answer, and the discord post).
`Float64`, and `Float32` are ideal names. Using anything else is unrequired. (And I hope julia never becomes that TIMTOWTDI)

Comment: (+1) Nicely answered @LyndonWhite, so what I understood is, and correct me if I'm wrong,  writing `Float64` will work just fine on 32-bit systems? My big concern is writing generic code that is also performant. BTW, Julia has a great community, it's my honor to be one of them.

Comment: you are correct Float64 will work fine on 32 bit systems.